# mysql not saving data on the development machine

Tags: mysql, vb.net, saving-data

My project (vb.net/mysql) has been working fine. Yesterday, I was debugging the project (on the development machine) and tried to edit/save some data and realized that it doesn't save the data to disk. No error messages are given! I quit debugging and rebuild the project and used the binary but it's the same! The weird thing is that the data is saved when I use the same binary to connect from a client machine. It even is saved when I connect from VMWare machine. Also, the same binary works fine when I connect from a client machine to the server machine. MySql Workbench on the development machine also works fine on all machines. I didn't change any code. I use this to save data:

```
CustomersBindingSource.EndEdit()
CustomersTableAdapter.Update(MainDataSet.customers)
```

The weirdest thing is that I have different places on my project where I use a simple mysql update query to update data, these work fine. So it's the code above that doesn't work but why it's working when I connect from a client machine?!

I'm completely lost on where I look for a solution.

Any help will be much appreciated

Development Environment: Windows 7 Pro 32 Bit, Visual Studio 2010, MySql v5.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with replacing the development machine with a new one. And now everything is working fine. This problem will be a mystery to me. I didn't get rid of the machine in case I might figure it out in the future. I gave it to my 10 year old son for gaming. Now he's happy and I'm happy.

End of story.